# do v. do*: Why does the same code produce a different result?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, reverse, sbcl, list-processing

I'm was playing around with the `do macro`, and I decided to write a function to reverse a list:

```
(defun my-reverse (my-list)
  (do ((alist my-list (cdr alist))
       (acc nil (cons (car alist) acc)))
      ((null alist) acc)
    (format t "current: ~a~%" (car alist))))

--output:--
CL-USER> (my-reverse '(10 20 30))
current: 10
current: 20
current: 30
(30 20 10)
```

All good so far.  But I discovered that changing `do` to `do*` produced a different result:

```
(defun my-reverse (my-list)
  (do* ((alist my-list (cdr alist))
        (acc nil (cons (car alist) acc)))
      ((null alist) acc)
    (format t "current: ~a~%" (car alist))))

--output:--    
(CL-USER> (my-reverse '(10 20 30))
current: 10
current: 20
current: 30
(NIL 30 20)
```

What is the explanation for that?

Also, because `(car alist)` appears twice in the code, I thought I would try to initialize a variable and set it equal to `(car alist)` in order to simplify the code:

```
(defun my-reverse (my-list)
  (do* ((alist my-list (cdr alist))
        (x (car alist))
        (acc nil (cons x acc)))
      ((null alist) acc)
    (format t "current: ~a~%" x)))

--output:--
CL-USER> (my-reverse '(10 20 30))
current: 10
current: 10
current: 10
(10 10 10)
```

Okay, `x` needs a stepper:

```
(defun my-reverse (my-list)
  (do* ((alist my-list (cdr alist))
        (x (car alist) (car alist))
        (acc nil (cons x acc)))
      ((null alist) acc)
    (format t "current: ~a~%" x)))

--output:--
CL-USER> (my-reverse '(10 20 30))
current: 10
current: 20
current: 30
(NIL 30 20)
```

That didn't work either.

Next, I tried doing the accumulation in the body:

```
(defun my-reverse (my-list)
  (do* ((alist my-list (cdr alist))
        (x (car alist) (car alist))
        (acc nil))
      ((null alist) acc)
    ((setf acc (cons x acc))
     (format "current: ~a~%")
     ))
```

But, I got an "illegal function call" error for:

```
(setf acc (cons x acc))
```

Is the body allowed to change the loop variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relation between `do` and `do*` is similar to that between `let` and `let*`: parallel assignment vs sequential.

Quoting from [the hyperspec](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_do_do.htm):

> For `do`, all the step-forms are evaluated before any var is updated; the assignment of values to vars is done in parallel, as if by `psetq`. *Because all of the step-forms are evaluated before any of the vars are altered, a step-form when evaluated always has access to the old values of all the vars, even if other step-forms precede it.*

So in `(cons (car alist) acc)`, the value of `alist` is the *previous* one, not what it's set to for this iteration.

Initially, `alist` is `'(10 20 30)`, and `acc` is `nil`. In the second iteration, `alist` is `'(20 30)` and `acc` is `'(10)`, and so on.

Whereas with `do*`,

> For `do*`, the first step-form is evaluated, then the value is assigned to the first var, then the second step-form is evaluated, then the value is assigned to the second var, and so on; the assignment of values to variables is done sequentially, as if by `setq`.

so it's seeing the current version of `alist`, which, in the second iteration is `'(20 30)` (And so 20 is appended to `acc`) and in the last iteration is `nil`, and `(car nil)` is `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

Your last try:

- a *body* can't have extra parentheses around it
- the `format` form additionally does need an output and an arg

The syntax for `DO*`:

1. a list of binding lists
2. a list with a test and result forms
3. then follow several statements or tags, the *body*

The corrected code:

```
(defun my-reverse (my-list)
  (do* ((list my-list      (rest list))  ; bindings
        (x    (first list) (first list)) ; bindings
        (acc  nil))                      ; bindings
       ((null list) acc)                 ; test & result
    (push x acc)                         ; body
    (format t "current: ~a~%" x)))       ; body
```

Note the indentation of above.

trying it:

```
CL-USER 1 > (my-reverse '(10 20 30))
current: 10
current: 20
current: 30
(30 20 10)
```

**Usage**

One would typically use `do` or `do*` when one needs to iterate over multiple things. This makes it necessary to understand the differences in bindings and scope -> also to test it.

For one list to iterate over, we can, for example, use `dolist`:

```
(defun my-reverse (list &aux result)
  (dolist (element list result)
    (push element result)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I learned a few things.  I'm not very good with emacs and I find I delete things all the time by accident. The error message I got didn't flag the format form as the problem, so I probably deleted part of the format form while copy pasting.